# No video shown in Ubuntu Touch QML app video player

Tags: ubuntu-touch, application-development, ubuntu-sdk, qml, multimedia

I'm trying to play a video in an Ubuntu Touch QML app. The audio plays, but no video is shown.

A minimalistic version:

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import Ubuntu.Components 1.2
import QtMultimedia 5.5

MainView {
    applicationName: "untitled.username"
    Video {
        anchors.fill: parent
        source: "http://feeds.nos.nl/~r/journaal20uur/~3/JRJKV6kpvRc/mp4_web03.mp4"
        autoPlay: true
    }
}
```

This works as expected when deploying on the desktop (i.e. video is shown). But on a BQ Aquaris 10 tablet only the audio is played, but no video is shown. I've tried to play a WebM, and local stored file too, but same results.

The app has AppArmor's networking and video Security Policy Group set. I'm using framework ubuntu-sdk-15.04.5. My device is on the current OTA11 rc.  Anything else I can try?

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question, it might be linked to [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/media-hub/+bug/1446260), which mentions problems streaming video over http. Indeed, if I store the mentioned file locally instead of streaming, it's shown correctly.

I guess the locally stored files I've tried earlier (WebM, Theora) might have other issues, but that seems unrelated to this issue.